# Opacity CheckBox(VisualStudio) don't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox

There's no code problem, the debug doesn't have any problem but when I test, when I checked the checkbox the opacity doesn't change. Nothing happen. I'm using VisualStudio 2013 Express. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TP3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int carac = textBox1.Text.Length;
            label2.Text = carac.ToString();

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form1;
            Form1 = new Form1();
            if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
             Form1.Opacity = 1;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't need to create a new instance of the form.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't seem to do anything right. You are creating a new instance of `Form` in the `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` method (why do you create a new form?), you set the Opacity property on the new form, but you do not show the form any way. You need to call `Show()` / `ShowDialog()` on the `Form1` to show it.

If you wish to change the opacity of the current form you can do it this way:

```
this.Opacity = 1;
```

And a call like without `this` would work as well:

```
Opacity = 1;
```